# Specific Join with Mysql

Tags: mysql

This is the query I would like to run :

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    history.name,
    history.id AS historyId
FROM
    order_sheet AS o
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        h.detail,
        h.eid,
        h.date_change
    FROM
        order_history AS h
    WHERE
        h.id_order_sheet = o.id
    ORDER BY
        h.id
    DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
) history
ON
    history.id_order_sheet = o.id
ORDER BY
    o.id
LIMIT 0, 150;
```

My issue from the second **select**. It don't know o.id.

Have you got any idea how to do this please?

I will explain what I what to do :)

I want to *select the last element* inserted in the table *order_history* with the value *order_history.id_order_sheet === to order_sheet.id*

Thank you for your help

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    history.name,
    history.id AS historyId
FROM
    order_sheet AS o
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        h.detail,
        h.eid,
        h.date_change
    FROM
        order_history AS h join order_sheet o1
    on
        h.id_order_sheet = o1.id
    ORDER BY
        h.id
    DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
) history
ON
    history.id_order_sheet = o.id
ORDER BY
    o.id
LIMIT 0, 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

We may rewrite your join using a non correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    h2.name,
    h2.id AS historyId
FROM order_sheet AS o
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_order_sheet, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM order_history
    GROUP BY id_order_sheet
) h1
    ON o.id = h1.id_order_sheet
INNER JOIN order_history h2
    ON h1.id_order_sheet = h2.id_order_sheet AND h1.id = h2.max_id
ORDER BY
    o.id
LIMIT 0, 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do would be a lateral join, which MySQL does not support yet.

However, it is not difficult to get that latest history record per order sheet ID. You don't need a join.

```
select id_order_sheet, name, id as history_id
from order_history
where id in (select max(id) from order_history group by id_order_sheet)
order by id_order_sheet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can't test this but here's one approach:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    h.name,
    h.id AS history_id,
    h.detail,
    h.eid,
    h.date_change
FROM order_sheet o
LEFT JOIN order_history h ON h.id_order_sheet = o.id
WHERE h.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM order_history
    GROUP by id_order_sheet
);
```